# Is there an AWS resource that allows Lambda invocation at irregular intervals?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to automate a time-consuming process:

I have nightly data ingestion process that concludes around 11:00 pm every evening. A second process is then kicked off manually the follow morning on certain dates.

I would like to automate this second process so it triggers at 3:00am on the dates that I specify.

The problem:

The necessity of this secondary process comes at non-regular intervals. For example, the next manual invocations of this morning process will be:
[
Monday, July 29th, 2019,
Monday, August 26th 2019,
Monday, September 23rd 2019,
Monday, November 25th 2019,
Monday, December 30th 2019,
]
Notice that these days are not a fixed distance from one another.

TLDR: Because I require a lambda function to trigger on an irregular schedule, I am looking for some resource that can act as an *irregular* cron scheduler for non standard intervals.

I have looked into `Event Patterns` in CloudWatch for possible solutions -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEventsandEventPatterns.html.

I saw many examples of regular cron schedules however was unable to find one who's frequency occurs at irregular intervals.

Comment: May be multiple scheduler event can help you to schedule in irregular interval.

Comment: Can I considerer a scenario where you will start second process after finsihing of first.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it has been done before by using a DynamoDB table with the irregular times.

There is an article about it, here: https://medium.com/swlh/scheduling-irregular-aws-lambda-executions-through-dynamodb-ttl-attributes-acd397dfbad9

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am following along with your suggestion. I appreciate the insight. Ill report back if any questions or concerns arise from this tutorial

Comment: If this information helped, please mark the answer as correct, so other user can easily find this solution.

Comment: since I'm also doing stuff with this, remember that it could take up to 48h to get the event deleted as by https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html